# Why RewriteCond is skipped if file not found?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Let's suppose I have something like this in my .htaccess file :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/
RewriteRule . index.php [QSA,L]
```

And there is only one image "abc.jpg" in the folder "images".

If I go to "www.mydomain.com/images/abc.jpg" the image will show up.

But if I go to "www.mydomain.com/images/123.jpg" this link will be rewrited to the file "index.php".

Is it normal? Is there a way to avoid this and have the default 404 browser page?

Comment: Above rule won't rewrite to `/index.php` if request starts with `/image/`

Comment: Curiously, it does if the requested file doesn't exist in the folder `/images/`